# Сохранение VkAccessToken android

Tags: android, vkontakte-api, android-vksdk

Пишу маленькое приложение вк для андроид в целях обучения. Сделал авторизацию с помощью вк, все хорошо, но каждый раз спрашивает доступ. Как правильно сохранить
VkAccessToken ? Я знаю что есть методы специальные - saveTokenToSharedPreferences и saveTokenToFile. Но вот как правильно их использовать не понимаю. Может кто знает ? Буду очень благодарен. Если можно пример кода для сохранения токена и его считывание для проверки авторизации пользователя. Спасибо !

Comment: Вроде в SDK есть метод типа isLogedIn - попробуйте его вызывать и если он false возвращает - запраивать вход

Comment: А он и никогда не будет true, если не сохранить токен. Или я что-то не понимаю ?

Comment: Юрий, спасибо большое за подсказку, вроде работает, как я раньше не додумался. Спасибо !!!!

Comment: Вы можете сами ответить на свой вопрос, приведя, кратко, получившийся код - это может помочь кому-то в будущем)

Comment: Так и сделаю ! Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В моем случае не нужно сохранять VkAccessToken. Нужно просто проверить авторизирован ли пользователь с помощью метода `isLoggedIn()`.
У меня так:

```
if (VKSdk.isLoggedin()==true){

       //тут осуществляется вход в программу без спрашивания разрешения


}

else {
     //тут запускается активити с авторизацией в вк

}
```

P.S.Спасибо Юрию )